# How to execute a perl program inside Map Reduce in Hadoop?

Tags: java, perl, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a perl program which will take a input file and process it and produce an output file as result. Now I need to use this perl program on hadoop. So that the perl program will run on data chunks stored on edge nodes thing is I shouldn't modify the perl code. I didn't know how to start this . Can someone please give me any advice ir suggestions.

Can I write a java program , in the mapper class call the perl program using process builder and combine the results in reducer class ??

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can do this with hadoop `streaming`.

As per `tom white`, author of `hadoop definitive guide, 3rd edition`. Page `# 622`, Appendix C.

He used `hadoop` to execute a bash `shell` script as a `mapper`.

In your case you need to use `perl script` instead of that `bash shell script`.

**Use Case:** He has a `lot of small files`(one big tar file input), his shell script converts them into `few big files`(one big tar file output).

He used hadoop to process them in parallel by giving `bash shell script` as mapper. Therefore this mapper works with input files parallely and produce results.

**example hadoop command:**(copy pasted)

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_INSTALL/contrib/streaming/hadoop-*-streaming.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
-D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false \
-D mapred.task.timeout=12000000 \
-input ncdc_files.txt \
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat \
-output output \
-mapper load_ncdc_map.sh \
-file load_ncdc_map.sh
```

Replace `load_ncdc_map.sh` with your `xyz.perl` in both places(last 2 lines in command).

Replace `ncdc_files.txt` with another text file which contains the list of your input files to be processed.(5th line from bottom)

**Assumptions Taken:** You have a fully functional hadoop cluster running and your perl script is error free.

Please try and let me know.

Comment: So I don't want to write a Map reduce java program ?? The thing is, it is an continuous process. We need to execute 4 or 5 scripts. For each scripts, the input will be the output of previous script. It is all sequential and batch processing.

Comment: @learner , Yes - you dont need to write a new MR program. You can reuse the above hadoop query with your modifications. I suggest to write a new parent.perl program which contains nothing but your 4-5 child-sequential.perl programs. Therefore you can give the parent.perl program as a mapper to hadoop, hadoop will run that perl program on the given nodes as a standalone program on that system. Please try and let me know.

Comment: what should I do if some of the scripts in perl and some are in python and some are in R. How do I do this scenario in hadoop map reduce wuth out modifying the scripts

Comment: @learner , If you are able to run all those programs together in a single program like a shell script which contains calls to these sub programs along with pipes for input-output passage in your machine as standalone (i.e without hadoop), then that one super-program can be given as a mapper to hadoop. The idea is, if you can run any program in standalone mode without any issues, then you can use it in hadoop also. In this way you dont need to change your perl/python/r code to work with hadoop. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks @Jagadish. I will try that. Can you please gimme some reference examples for this. Since I haven't done any shell scripting I am Struggling with how to start this.

Comment: Welcome @learner, refer to the book example as I mentioned above and you dont need to stick with shell script, I just suggested one way, you can even write the super-program in perl or python, which ever you are comfortable with. Please take this as a guidance/reference and proceed(as the scope of the question is completed here). And for further queries related to python/perl/shell, you can raise another QA thread. By the way if this answered your question then mark as done.

Answer (score 0):

Process builder in any java program is used to call non-java applications or scripts. Process builder should work when called from the mapper class. You need to make sure that the perl script, the perl executable and the perl libraries are available for all mappers.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to the party...

I'm about to start using Hadoop::Streaming. This seems to be the consensus module to use.